# Why can't a timestamp field get a default value?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, default, mysql-5.7, sql-mode

I try the following alter table:
`ALTER TABLE test MODIFY COLUMN a timestamp NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01';`

The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
 `a` timestamp NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

My sql_mode is:

```
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,
NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,
NO_ZERO_DATE,
ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,
NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,
NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

The error I get is : `#1067 - Unknown error 1067` 
Other thing that baffles me, why it doesn't show the actual error?

Comment: I think it's because it's a timestamp. A timestamp default value is NOW(). Try changing it to a DATETIME with a default.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, your server has [`ALLOW_INVALID_DATES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates) disabled.

> The server requires that month and day values be legal, and not merely
>   in the range 1 to 12 and 1 to 31, respectively. With strict mode
>   disabled, invalid dates such as '2004-04-31' are converted to
>   '0000-00-00' and a warning is generated. ***With strict mode enabled,
>   invalid dates generate an error. To permit such dates, enable*** `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES`

Comment: What is wrong with the date 1970-01-01 00:00:01 this is timestamp == 1